# Why do i get error 500?

Tags: php

for some reason i get error 500 in this file:

http://apps.sce.ac.il/testxml/parser.php

this is the `phpinfo()`:
**http://apps.sce.ac.il/testxml/phpinfo.php**

this is the code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
 'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'events.xml' );

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);

$b = $doc->createElement("record");

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
$event->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $event );

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $eventDate );

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);

$b->appendChild( $desc );
$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );

$doc->save("events.xml");

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    
?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled in php.ini?

Comment: Do you have access to your `error.log`? Then check there for the exact reason of the error.

Comment: I don't get a 500 error. The script redirects me to this page if i just click the link (which seems correct, given your Location header in the bottom). If no 'referer' is available, that might be the reason of your 500.

Comment: Well...it's works now. weird...

Comment: did your parser use too much system memory?

Comment: I thinks that the reson is that they upgrade the server for php5, so maybe i was in the middle of the upgrade when i test it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have turned off error reporting, which lets your webserver only transmit the error code.

try putting this at the top of your php file script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

then you should see your exact error.

you can also check your webserver logs.

Comment: Thanks m8..i will use it for another page :)